# Two-way TLS Angular + Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, angular-cli

I am trying to make an application that can be made through mTLS. Self-signed certificates are valid and recognized by the browser.

This is the configuration from Spring Boot:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-alias=localhost
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
```

And that's how I start the Angular application:

```
ng serve --open --ssl true --ssl-cert <cert-path>client.crt --ssl-key <key-path>client.key
```

If I make a request from Postman, the client's certificates are recognized and the request is made successfully, but when I make a request from Angular, I get the error `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`

**Problem solved**

The problem was due to the certificate used by ng serve. The certificate had to be signed with my CA and had to contain Subject Alternative Name: DNS Name=localhost.
I followed this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security, but for the client certificates I used:

1. openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout client.key -out client.csr -config certificate.cnf
2. openssl x509 -req -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -in client.csr -out client.crt -days 365 -CAcreateserial -extfile localhost.ext

localhost.ext - from the tutorial

certificate.cnf:

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
x509_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C = UK
ST = Hertfordshire
L = Watford
O = App
OU = App Unit
emailAddress = admin@gmail.com
CN = localhost

[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

Comment: Angular has nothing to do with it, it's 100% a browser/server problem. The client cert should be in the browser only. When you run ng serve, you should give it the server certificate. ng serve = run a server